# How to use enum class in switch case

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors, switch-statement, java-7

Am getting error - *case expressions must be constant expressions* , when am trying to use enum class in switch case statements :

My enum class is,

```
public enum TestEnumClass {

    TEST1("TEST1"),
    TEST2("TEST2"),
    TEST3("TEST3");

    private String enumConstant;

    private TestEnumClass(String algoConstant) {
        this.enumConstant = algoConstant;
    }

    public String getEnumConstant() {
        return enumConstant;
    } 
}
```

And am trying to use enum TestEnumClass  as below  in another class file,

```
public class TestIndexOf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String str = args[0];

        switch(str){

        case TestEnumClass.Test1.getEnumConstant() : System.out.println("test1"); break;

        case TestEnumClass.Test2.getEnumConstant() : System.out.println("test2"); break;

        }
    }
}
```

Its giving me compile time error :

> case expressions must be constant expressions

Please suggest me, where am I going wrong.

Comment: The values you are checking against need to be constants which are known at compile time. `TestEnumClass.Test1.getEnumConstant()` isn't considered constant, even though it doesn't change in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the info, how do I use it then? Moving enum to Static constant is the only way? But I want to use enums only.. Any way for this?

Comment: You have a few choices. You can use `final static String`s, you can use `if`s instead of a switch, or you can switch on `TestEnumClass.valueOf(str)` and have the `case`s be the enum values themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the result of methods as cases in a switch statement. Switches are optimised for constant cases. Enums are very suitable for this, but you would have to have:

```
TestEnumClass value = TestEnumClass.valueOf(str);

switch (value) {
    case TEST1: ...
    case TEST2: ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changed liked below, and its working great : TestEnumClass str = TestEnumClass.valueOf(args[0]);
  switch(str){
  
  case TEST1 : System.out.println("test1"); break;
  
  case TEST2 : System.out.println("test2"); break;
    
  }

Answer (score 1):

your `switch` expression is on a `String`, you need to change it to a variable of type `TestEnumClass`

Comment: …and then change the `case` labels to `TEST1`, `TEST2` and `TEST3`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `switch` over `String` but the `case` `TestEnumClass.TEST1.getEnumConstant()` is not compile time constant according to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).  A `case` statement requires compile time constant value. In order to correct the error you can do like this

```
String str = args[0];

TestEnumClass e = TestEnumClass.valueOf(str);

switch(e){

case TEST1: System.out.println("test1"); break;

case TEST2 : System.out.println("test2"); break;

}
```